# Slick.js customizing dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to customize the standard dots that come with slick.js.
I have a class "transparent-circle" that I want to use as dots and when the dot is active I want to use the class "active"

This what my classes look like:

```
.transparent-circle {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
  -webkit-border-radius:75px;
  -moz-border-radius:75px;
}

.active{
  background-color: rgba(126, 222, 186, 1);
  border: 2px solid #7EDEBA !important;
}
```

Here's what I've tried to customize the dots. I've been trying to do it with jquery in my document.ready function

```
$('.slick-dots li button').remove();
$('.slick-dots li').addClass('transparent-circle');
```

So I want to remove the standard buttons and add the css class to the list items but nothing seems to be happening, unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run your function*s* **after Slick initialized**.

So this is an example , using on `init`

**Add this before your setup :**

```
$('.your-element').on('init', function(event, slick){
   var $items = slick.$dots.find('li');
   $items.addClass('transparent-circle');
   $items.find('button').remove();
});

// Setup
$('.your-element').slick({
   // ....
});
```

Comment: This is genius! Thanks a lot friend! I now need to find a way to inject the active class instead of the standard slick-active class

Comment: @I2aelba what would you recommend to switch the slick-active class with active?

Answer (score 4):

#### In external script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".your-slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    customPaging: function(slider, i) {      
      return '<div class="custom-slick-dots" id=' + i + "></div>";
    }
  });
});
```

Apply your styles to `.custom-slick-dots`

Then for the active state, apply your styles to `.slick-active .custom-slick-dots`

You can customise the `div` as you wish.

P.S. Sorry if this is not a tailored answer...it's more of a general one for anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#yourID').slick({
        ...,
        customPaging: function(slider, i) {
            return ''; // Remove button, customize content of "li"
        }
    });

$('#yourID .slick-dots li').addClass('transparent-circle'); //  Add class to "li"
```